# Rails - Get Paperclip URL using SQL Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am currently working on Rails application. every thing is fine. i written sql query and got the image_file_name like `Photo.all.select("photos.id, photos.image_file_name")` but i also want to parse full url of image. So is there any way can do this for me?

I need output like

```
[
  #<Photo id: 1, image_file_name: photo1, image_url: '/system/photos/images/000/000/86/thumb/photo1.png?1511864359'>, 
  #<Photo id: 2, image_file_name: photo2, image_url: '/system/photos/images/000/000/382/thumb/photo2.png?1511864359'>, 
  #<Photo id: 3, image_file_name: photo3, image_url: '/system/photos/images/000/000/102/thumb/photo3.png?1511864359'>, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure but somehow it can help you.

```
Photo.all.collect{|p| [p.id, p.image_file_name, p.image.path]}
```

this will give you result like this as array and you can traverse it as an array: -

```
[[4,"photo1","/system/photos/images/000/000/86/thumb/photo1.png?1511864359"],
 [5,"photo2","/system/photos/images/000/000/382/thumb/photo2.png?1511864359'"],
 [6,"photo3","/system/photos/images/000/000/102/thumb/photo3.png?1511864359"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will give you the result as you require:

```
Photo.select { |p| [p.id, p.image_file_name, p.image.path] }
```